# Python numpy index is out of bound for axis zero

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a code written in Python similar to the following:

```
def adamic_adar_prediction(graph):
    adjacencyMatrix = graph.get_adjacency()
    AAMatrix = adamic_adar_score(graph)
    AAMatrix  = np.array(AAMatrix)
    i = (-AAMatrix ).argsort(axis=None, kind='mergesort')
    j = np.unravel_index(i, AAMatrix .shape)
    sortedList = np.vstack(j).T
    print(sortedList.size)

    print(sortedList[1658943])
    print(sortedList[1658945])
```

While the result of the first print is 3,316,888 I receive the following error for the last print:

`IndexError: index 1658944 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1658944`

Any idea why this error arises for my array?

Comment: Use `print(sortedList[1658943])` instead.

Comment: Could you provide the exact code? How 'similar' is this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all of the comments. I figured my problem is that sortedList.size returns total number of elements in the array while I was expecting the number of tuples in my array (since sortedList is a list of tuples [[],[],...]). So I solved my problem using `sortedList.shape`

Answer (score 2):

You don't have enough elements in your `array`, for example:

```
In [5]: import numpy as np

In [6]: a = np.array([1,2])

In [8]: a[2] # there is no element at 2nd index
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-016a87a854bc> in <module>()
----> 1 a[2]

IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

Comment: But as I have mentioned, the size of my numpy array is 3,317,888 !

Comment: @nimafl, are you sure? The error message says otherwise, and `3,316,888` seems to be value at index `1658943`.

Comment: Absolutely. The value at 1658943 is [1287 1286].

Comment: @nimafl, I see, in your questions you trying to get values at `1658943` and `1658945`, but you error message shows `1658944`, so it seems like you are not actually executing that code. Unfortunately, I can't help much more than this, but to me it feels like some silly mix up somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Considering how mysterious your problem is, I'd go ahead and test this with a try/except loop to be sure the code goes past that point and is only having issues at index 1658944...

something like:

```
for x in range(sortedList.size):
    try:
        sortedList[x]
    except:
        print "no index at", x
```

Report back what your results are.